# Remap one of the two Tilde/swiggly keys to become Right-Shift key

Tags: keyboard, shift, remap, tilde

I have purchased a used laptop, Shinelon TN15S (China-based company). The keyboard layout in one glance looks normal, however once I've started using it, there is one major annoyance.[image]

This keyboard has two tilde/swiggly keys. The upper-left key is fine as that is what I always use, but the one on the lower-right is not. What makes me annoyed is that it makes the Right-Shift key becomes shorter like a single key. So I frequently "accidentally" pressed the lower-right tilde/swiggly key when I intend to use the Right-Shift key.

So far, I've tried to use a few keyboard remapper software like SharpKeys and Powertoys for Win10. However, these 2 keys are not independent - if I remap the lower-right tilde/swiggly key to become right-shift key, the upper-left also becomes the shift key as well.

I also look at AutoHotkey, but I'm not sure if it can be used for this, and I'm not very good at writing scripts as well. If anyone has similar keyboard layout like this and can point me to the solution, I would be very much appreciated.